# question about the conditional disjoint probability.

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, poisson-process

I am trying to solve a problem like the following.

---

> Q) The event that a man arrives at a bank $\sim Poisson(\lambda)$. If two men visited the bank between 9:30 AM and 10:30 AM, what is the probability that both entered before 10:00 AM?

---

The solution:
\begin{align}
\mbox{S_1} & \mbox{: the time when the first man entered.}\\
\mbox{S_2} & \mbox{: the time when the second man entered.}\\
\mbox{N(t)} & \mbox{: the number of event occurred in (0, t]}\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
f_{S_1, S_2\mid N(1)=2} (s_1, s_2 \mid 2) = 2, && 0<s_1<s_2<1 \\
\end{align}

$$\therefore P\left.\left[S_2\le\frac12\right | N(1)=2\right] = \frac14$$

---

My trial:
\begin{align}
\mbox{S_1} & \mbox{: the time when the first man entered.}\\
\mbox{S_2} & \mbox{: the time when the second man entered.}\\
\mbox{N(t)} & \mbox{: the number of event occurred in (0, t]}\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
f_{S_1, S_2|N(1)=2} (s_1, s_2 \mid 2) = 2, && 0<s_1<s_2<1 \\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
P\left.\left[S_2\le\frac12\right|N(1)=2\right] &= P\left.\left[S_1\le\frac12, S_2\le\frac12\right|N(1)=2\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac12}\int_{0}^{\frac12} f_{S_1, S_2|N(1)=2} (s_1, s_2 | 2) {ds_1}{ds_2}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac12}\int_{0}^{\frac12} 2 {ds_1}{ds_2}\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}

---

My answer and the solution are different. I guess the solution used conditional Poisson process $\sim$ Uniform distribution. However, I want to solve the problem with conditional pdf. Can someone help me? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Why are you doing this  part "$P\left.\left[S_1\le\frac12, S_2\le\frac12\right|N(1)=2\right]$"? Isn't $S_1\leq \frac{1}{2}\cap S_2 \leq \frac{1}{2} = S_2\leq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @probablyme because $S_1$ should be smaller than $S_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are doing, but I think your bounds are wrong.
It might be $0\leq s_1 \leq s_2$.
\begin{align}
P\left.\left[S_2\le\frac12\right|N(1)=2\right] &= P\left.\left[S_1\le\frac12, S_2\le\frac12\right|N(1)=2\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac12}\int_{0}^{s_2} f_{S_1, S_2|N(1)=2} (s_1, s_2 | 2) {ds_1}{ds_2}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac12}\int_{0}^{s_2} 2 {ds_1}{ds_2}\\
&=\int_0^\frac{1}{2}2[s]_0^{s_2}\,ds_2\\
&=\int_0^\frac{1}{2}2s_2\,ds_2\\
&=2\cdot\frac{1}{2}[s_2^2]_0^\frac{1}{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}

Comment: Oh, my god... I am so shy because I missed the thing which is very fundamental and important!! thank you very much... Why couldn't I find this!!! :(

Comment: @Danny_Kim Don't worry, it happens :)